# React-Native: Pressing on the keyboard (textInput) causes the header to slide off the screen. How can it be kept in the same position?

Tags: android, react-native, android-softkeyboard

Currently, I'm getting the page this way after pressing on text input (notice there's no header, since it's popped out of the screen):

[image]

I want it to be like this (even if I press on text input, HEADER should remain in the same position):
[image]

I'm using this in the android manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Dimensions,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  Text,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
} from 'react-native';
const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');

const Conversation = ({}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar hidden />
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'gray',
          height: 50,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <Text center style={{color: 'white'}}>
          Header
        </Text>
      </View>

      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={{flex:1}}>
        <TextInput
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            borderWidth: 1,
            height: 50,
            marginHorizontal: width * 0.1,
            top: height * 0.9,
          }}
        />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </>
  );
};

export default Conversation;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove `top: height * 0.9` and place your content inside ScrollView.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
     View,
     Dimensions,
     TextInput,
     ScrollView,
     StatusBar,
     Text,
     FlatList,
     KeyboardAvoidingView,
} from 'react-native';
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const Conversation = ({ }) => {
return (
<>
  <StatusBar hidden />
  <View
    style={{
      backgroundColor: 'gray',
      height: 50,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    }}>
    <Text center style={{ color: 'white' }}>
      Header
    </Text>
  </View>

  <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <ScrollView>

    </ScrollView>
    <TextInput
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderWidth: 1,
        height: 50,
        marginHorizontal: width * 0.1
      }}
    />
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</>
);
};

export default Conversation
```

Comment: Yes, now it's fixed. However, I can see a little bump in the header when I press on textInput. Do you know the workaround for this?